# Swift 3 Custom pull-to-refresh view drifts (decelerates) under certain circumstances

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I’ve been working through an animations tutorial from Raywenderlich.com and I noticed an annoying bug in one of their demo projects. The project was to implement a custom pull-to-refresh animation. You can see from this gif that there is a bit of continuing deceleration after releasing the refresh trigger:

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LpUA.gif)

After pulling the hair out of my head for a while, I was able to narrow the problem to the specific case when pulling down to refresh where the lowest cell in the tableView dips out of the viewable area of the screen. In other words, running the iphone 7+ simulator, this problem doesn't occur if I increase (20) or decrease (5) the number of cells in the table view.

Here are the relevant methods:

```
      // MARK: Scroll View Delegate methods

  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = max(-(scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top), 0.0)
    progress = min(max(offsetY / frame.size.height, 0.0), 1.0)

    if !isRefreshing {
      redrawFromProgress(self.progress)
    }
  }

  func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    if !isRefreshing && self.progress >= 1.0 {
        delegate?.refreshViewDidRefresh(self)

      beginRefreshing()
    }
  }
```